# VBA - ReDim Preserve creating false array element

Tags: excel, vba

This is a for loop to find values in a range and create new array full of match results. Problem is viewing the object I see at the first If statement AR2(i) creates an element AR2(0) which is empty then assigns AR2(1) as the If Else value.

```
Sub rt()
Dim AR0() As Variant, AR1() As Variant, AR2() As Variant
Dim WS0 As Worksheet, WS1 As Worksheet
Dim i As Integer, RW0 As Integer, RW1 As Integer
Dim C As Range

Set WS0 = Sheets("lookup")
Set WS1 = Sheets("centro")

RW1 = WS1.Cells(WS1.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).row
AR0 = WS0.Range("A3:A28")

For i = 1 To UBound(AR0, 1)
    With WS1.Range("A2:A" & RW1)
        Set C = .find(AR0(i, 1), LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext)
        ReDim Preserve AR2(i)
        If Not C Is Nothing Then
            AR2(i) = "YES"
        Else
            AR2(i) = " - "
        End If
    End With
Next

WS0.Range("B3:B28") = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(AR2)

End Sub
```

Comment: Yes, this is how it works when you don't explicitly set your array's lower limit, it sets it at 0.  What is the problem?  You can explicitly set it with `ReDim Preserve AR2(1 to i)`.

Comment: by default, arrays are 0 based in VBA.  Since you're starting your counter off at 1, the first element has to be 0.  Modify your logic to either loop from 0 to Ubound (AR0,1) -1 or subtract one when populating your array.

Comment: @ RBarryYoung - The problem is that I want to transpose the newly created array AR2 to the sheet, but in the loop AR(0) is created first as "empty" then AR(1) is assigned a value based off of the IF statement. Ultimately the transposed array is off by a count of 1.

Comment: Using `ReDim Preserve` in a loop is a bad idea since you are continually allocating and then garbage-collecting arrays, copying the elements in the process. This makes it quadratic in the number of passes through the loop. Why not ReDim the array just once *before* you enter the loop? Alternatively -- consider using a collection. The difference between a quadratic and a linear algorithm could easily be hours of cpu time vs. seconds of cpu time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Error was with AR2 creating element AR2(0) without having value assigned. Solution was to set For loop to start from 0 and AR0(i +1, 1) to allow to find this value starting from loop position 0. Thanks!

```
    Sub rt()
    Dim AR0() As Variant, AR1() As Variant, AR2() As Variant
    Dim WS0 As Worksheet, WS1 As Worksheet
    Dim i As Integer, RW0 As Integer, RW1 As Integer
    Dim C As Range

    Set WS0 = Sheets("lookup")
    Set WS1 = Sheets("centro")

    RW1 = WS1.Cells(WS1.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).row
    AR0 = WS0.Range("A3:A28")

    For i = 0 To UBound(AR0, 1) - 1
        With WS1.Range("A2:A" & RW1)
            Set C = .find(AR0(i + 1, 1), LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext)
            ReDim Preserve AR2(i)
            If Not C Is Nothing Then
                AR2(i) = "YES"
            Else
                AR2(i) = " - "
            End If
        End With
    Next

    WS0.Range("B3:B28") = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(AR2)

    End Sub
```